# make return button on keyboard perform an action

Tags: iphone, sdk, uisearchbar

I have a searchbox. I want to make it so when the user pushes search on there keyboard it performs and IBAction. How can i link that key to the -(IBAction)Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There one delegate method which is fired when search button is pressed

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

{

      //CALL YOUR IBACTION METHOD HERE
}
```

-Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self yourButtonName:nil];
}
```